# Recover corrupted Dataset from Designer generated code

Tags: c#, vb.net, xsd, designer

Anybody have ideas as to how to recover Visual Studio (2010) DataSet XSD files from the Designer generated code files.

I have several Dataset's some of which have been corrupted, the corruption have occured in the Designer part of the dataset meaning the XSD file the ones that enable the graphical changing of tables, columns and so forth. I still have the Designer.vb/cs, xsc and xss files all intact.
But in order to make changes to these dataset's i need the Designer xsd files.

Do any of you know of a way to reverse engineer the Designer.vb/cs filer back into the XSD file??

We are talking about large Datasets, so redoing them manually from analyzing the code files is a last resort.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Open your XSD file in notepad and you should see an XML formatted document, either you can post that on here in case anyone can spot anything or try looking yourself in there.

Comment: The corruption has resulted in 95% of the XSD to be missing. so posting that won't do much good. It's not a matter of correcting some tags or likewise (unfortunately) but rather to re-create the XSD from the code.

Comment: I don't now if any of these links can help you (link 1-last thread) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/955181d4-dbe5-42c7-a8e2-69f1b91dda86     (link 2) http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/markwillems/archive/2011/02/16/biztalk-schema-build-error.aspx     (link -3 may be best shot) http://www.ehow.com/how_6741903_create-xsd-xml-file.html